# parsing WinDbg output in real-time and setting a trigger on a specific line of output

Tags: windows, debugging, windbg, pykd

Is there any way to parse the output of `WinDbg` and set a "trigger" on a specific line of output? I mean - executing a line of `WinDbg` script / `pykd` script when a specific line of output appears.

I've tried performing this using `WinDbg` scripting, but I was unsuccessful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to control the debugger using [`OutputDebugString()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa363362(v=vs.85).aspx), then have a look at [`.ocommand`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/debugger/-ocommand--expect-commands-from-target-).

Otherwise I'm not aware of something that could directly achieve what you want. You could write a PyKD script that runs forever and emulates the command prompt. You could then use [`dbgCommand()`](https://pykd.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=PYKD%200.3.%20API%20Reference&referringTitle=Documentation#dbgCommand) to execute the command and get the result back as a string. Forward it to the output and analyze it in order to run a script.

Comment: Thomas, could you please explain what you mean by "a PyKD script that runs forever and emulates the command prompt"? Thank you very much for the answer.

Answer (score 2):

with pykd you can try make your own eventHandler:

```
class outputHandler(pykd.eventHandler):

     def onDebugOutput(self, str):
          if str == "something interesting":
              do_handler()

eh = outputHandler()
```

Then you should run you script with 'global' interpreter:

```
!py -g my_script.py
```

I hope it will work